# How to connect Azure Data Factory with SQL Endpoints instead of interactive cluster?

Tags: azure, azure-data-factory, azure-databricks

Is it possible to connect Azure Data Factory with Azure Databricks SQL Endpoints (Delta table and views) instead of interactive cluster. I tried with Azure delta lake connector but it has options for cluster and not Endpoints?

Comment: what do you want to achieve? what kind of operations do you want to run on Databricks?

Comment: can you please share your use case what you are trying to achieve . Databricks SQL is used as federated query engine against storage accounts not for ETL process . In that case , by using of Databricks SQL you can use for interactive query . Not scheduled manner loading .

Comment: Please clarify your specific problem or provide additional details to highlight exactly what you need. As it's currently written, it's hard to tell exactly what you're asking.

Answer (score 1):

> Unfortunately, you cannot connect Azure Databricks SQL endpoints with Azure Databricks using ADF.

**Note:** With compute option - you can connect Azure Databricks workspace with the below cluster options:

- New Job cluster
- Existing interactive cluster
- Existing instance pool

[image]

**Note:** With Datastore option - Azure Databricks Delta Lake option you can connect only existing interactive clusters:

[image]

Appreciate if you could share the feedback on our [feedback channel](https://feedback.azure.com/d365community/forum/1219ec2d-6c26-ec11-b6e6-000d3a4f032). Which would be open for the user community to upvote & comment on. This allows our product teams to effectively prioritize your request against our existing feature backlog and gives insight into the potential impact of implementing the suggested feature.